# Multiple index locations Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to Solr, and am trying to figure out the best way to index and search our catalogs.

We have to index multiple manufactures and each manufacturer has a different catalog per country.  Each catalog for each manufacture per country is about 8GB of data.

I was thinking it might be easier to have an index per manufacture per country and have some way to tell Solr in the URL which index to search from.

Is that the best way of doing this?  If so, how would I do it? Where should I start looking?  If not, what would be the best way?

I am using Solr 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general there are two ways of solving this:

1. Split each catalog into its own core, running a large multi core setup. This will keep each index physically separated from each other, and will allow you to use different properties (language, etc) and configuration for each core. This might be practical, but will require quite a bit of overhead if you plan on searching through all the core at the same time. It'll be easy to split the different cores into running on different servers later - simply spin the cores up on a different server.
2. Run everything in a single core - if all the attributes and properties of the different catalogs are the same, add two fields - one containing the manufacturer and one containing the country. Filter on these values when you need to limit the hits to a particular country or manufacturer. It'll allow you to easily search the complete index, and scalability can be implemented by replication or something like SolrCloud (coming in 4.0). If you need multilanguage support you'll have to have a field for each language with the settings you need for that language (such as stemming).

There are a few tidbits of information about this on the Solr wiki, but my suggestion is to simply try one of the methods and see if that solves your issue. Moving to the other solution shouldn't be too much work. The simplest implementation is to keep everything in the same index.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. Number 2 seems to look the best for my situation.